# how do multiple remainders* in a series work in java?

Tags: subprocess

so basically, how does $1.26 turn into:

```
Dollars: 1
Quarters: 1
Pennies: 1
```

thanks! edited title to remainders instead of modulo operators

```
int change = (int)(changeDue*100);

int dollars = (int)(change/100);
change=change%100;
int quarters = (int)(change/25);
change=change%25;
int pennies = (int)(change/1);
change=change%1

System.out.println("Dollars: " + dollars);
System.out.println("Quarters: " + quarters);
System.out.println("Pennies: " + pennies);
```

Comment: Replace "modulo operator" with **remainder**. What is the remainder of `126/100`, it's 26.... try the rest of the values...

Comment: We have `change = change % 100;`, and we've established that `126 % 100` is `26`. So, after `change = 26;` what value does `change` have?

Comment: **It** knows how to "organize" nothing.  The **programmer** who wrote this "organized" the code by writing the statements in a certain order to make it work that way.

Comment: @spider249 No, it's like assignment, which *replaces* the previous value of the variable (left side of assignment operator) with the result of the expression (right side of assignment operator).

Comment: ok thanks @Andreas i get it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The modulo operation gives the remainder of a division. 
Values in a %-operation `a % m` always range from `0` to `m - 1`.

```
change=change%100; // divides by 100 and leaves the remainder which is less than a dollar
change=change%25; // divides by 25 and leaves the remainder which is less than a quarter
change=change%10; // divides by 10 and leaves the remainder which is less than a dime
change=change%5; // divides by 5 and leaves the remainder which is less than a nickel
change=change%1 // this operation is always 0 because an integer can always be divided by 1 without a remainder
```

Answer (score 0):

For each denomination you need to do integer division, then modulo:

- Integer division is ignoring reminder of a division, e.g. 126/100=1
- Modulo returns only a reminder of a division, e.g. 126%100=26

So for 126 cents you need 1 dollar. And repeat the same thing with reminder value for each smaller denomination. For quarter, you will get for 26/25=1 quarter and reminder is 26%1, which is 1... You get the idea.